# postfix - rules for relayhost

Tags: postfix, smarthost

I'm using postfix as my smarthost(relayhost) for an exchange cluster, it works great.  But we are working on setting up encrypted email for some of our customers, so I'm trying to take email from SOME domains and direct it to another smarthost, but everyone else, deliver as normal.

Basically I'm trying to do what the transports file does but based on the FROM address, not the TO address.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

you are probably looking for [sender_dependent_relayhost_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps)